# Which can support more weight, one thick rope or many thinner ropes?

Tags: forces, material-science, moduli

Given the same total amount of material used and the same length of an individual rope, will many thinner ropes support more weight (withstand more tension) than one thick rope?

Comment: Keep in mind that the thick rope is merely a twisted version of many smaller strands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What withstands tension is molecular bonds, so what matters is just the surface area across which the load is carried. Multiple thin ropes with the same total area as one thick rope should withstand tension just as well as the thick rope.

...except that "a chain is not stronger than its weakest link". If one rope breaks if there are multiple ropes this is not a disaster, but it is when there is just one rope.

If there are N fibers and the probability of one breaking as a function of the load on it is $P(F)$, then the probability that none will break is $(1-P(F))^N$. If $N$ is large this is $\approx 1$, as long as $P(F)$ does not increase fast for thinner fibers.